# Synapse spark select column with space

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I am trying to read synapse table, which has spaces in column names.

Read table is working until I am selecting columns without spaces or special characters:

```scala
%%spark
val df = spark.read.synapsesql("<Pool>.<schema>.<table>").select("TYPE", "Year").limit(100)
df.show()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```scala
+------+----+
|  TYPE|Year|
+------+----+
|BOUGHT|LAST|
|BOUGHT|LAST|
|BOUGHT|LAST|
|BOUGHT|LAST|
```

When I start selecting columns with spaces I am getting errors. I have tried many variants:

```
.select(col("""`Country Code`"""))
.select(col("`Country Code`"))
.select(col("""[Country Code]"""))
.select(col("Country Code"))
.select($"`Country Code`")
.select("`Country Code`")
.select("""`Country Code`""")
```

will return this error:
**ERROR: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'Country'.**

If I ommit `` ` `` in select for example:

```
.select("[Country Code]")
```

**ERROR: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name '[Country Code]'.**

With back-tick spark in synapse just take only first word as column.

Any experience?

Comment: Have you tried df.printSchema() [without a select clause] to see what Spark shows as the column names?

Comment: yes and I was already chcecking whether space is really space (and space is regular char(32)). I have connection in MSSQL studio so I can see all table details. and this column is there. Do you have opportunity to try it in your sybase environment?

Comment: I got it to work by using `` in the original select: .select("Id", "`Country Code`")

Comment: This I have tryied as well :-/.

Comment: Not doubting you, but the comment did not render properly - there should be back ticks inside the double quotes around Country Code.

Comment: I understood. As I said have tried everyrhing. The point is I think this is not the way how it should it work. And i think that all selects abovementioned are correct and should work. If I try .select("""[Country Code]""") error is: Invalid column name '[Country Code]', but if I run select and speficy column with ` error says: column name 'Country'.

Comment: The `select` on its own will work @JoelCochran, adding `.show` (or any other action like `count`) will not.  There does seem to be an issue with the Synapse `synapsesql` API.  The `Invalid column name 'country'` error is coming from the SQL engine because it seems like there is no way to pass square brackets back to it, it seems.  Also parquet files don't support spaces in column names so it's probably connected.  The workaround is to simply not use spaces in column names.  Fix up the tables in a previous Synapse pipeline step if required.  I'll have a look into it but may be no other answer.

Comment: Connection with parquet is a good point. I know that spaces in column names are bad, but this schema was provided to me. My task was clear: Create POC using synapse and spark. This can be bypassed using spark with ODBC connection, and read data from VIEW, where columns are correct. I was just interested, If somebody other met with this. FYI: Read data using `spark.read.synapsesql` from VIEW with right column names return **error: no data to read.**

Comment: If it's just a PoC, just run through all the columns with spaces and fix them up:, eg `EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.countries.country Type', 'countryType', 'COLUMN';`

Comment: Just for completeness, I also tested it with a Spark SQL temporary View (renaming the column in the SELECT using back ticks) and received the same error. I think @wBob is correct, you are going to have to address the column names in the SQL Pool. Can you create a VIEW to handle the rename?

Comment: That particular API (`sysnapsesql.read`) can't handle views unfortunately.  You would have to materialise it eg using a CTAS in a prior Synapse Pipeline step.  The API useful for simple patterns (get table -> process -> put back) but is pretty limited.  You can't even manage table distribution (hash, round_robin, replicate) or indexing (clustered columnstore, clustered index, heap) or partitioning but you never know they might add to it one day.  I'll be keeping on eye out during the next MS conference anyway.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I'm really surprised that View isn't supported.

Comment: @Joel Cochram thats cruel sad true.

Comment: @PeterTrcka Were you able to resolve the issue. I am facing a similar issue and I am stuck and tried all the options you have mentioned

Comment: Matt yes, the most simple way I had found was to create a view (with spark valid column names) and query the view instead of the table itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the function to run query using `JDBC`. Thanks this I was able to read from view. I have added saplme code how to get password from KeyVault, using `TokenLibrary`.

```py
def spark_query(db, query):
    jdbc_hostname = "<synapse_db>.sql.azuresynapse.net"
    user = "<spark_db_client>"
    password = "<strong_password>"
    # password_from_kv = TokenLibrary.getSecret("<Linked_Key_Vault_Service_Name>", "<Key_Vault_Key_Name>", "<Key_Vault_Name>")
    return spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbc_hostname }:1433;databaseName={db};user={user};password={password}") \
    .option("query", query) \
    .load()
```

Then I have created `VIEW` with column names without spaces:

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_my_table
AS
SELECT [Country code] as country_code from my_table
```

Granted access to `<spark_db_client>`:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON v_my_table to <spark_db_client>
```

After whole preparation I was able to read table from VIEW and save to `spark` database:

```py
query = """
SELECT country_code FROM dbo.v_my_table
"""

df = spark_query(db="<my_database>", query=query)
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS spark_poc")
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("spark_poc.my_table")
df.registerTempTable("my_table")
```

This are `<placeholder_variables>`

Answer (score 1):

The `select` on its own will work, adding `show` (or any other action like `count`) will not. There does seem to be an issue with the Synapse `synapsesql` API. The Invalid column name 'country' error is coming from the SQL engine because it seems like there is no way to pass square brackets back to it. Also parquet files do not support spaces in column names so it's probably connected.

The workaround is to simply **not** use spaces in column names. Fix up the tables in a previous Synapse pipeline step if required. I'll have a look into it but may be no other answer.

If you want to rename existing columns in the database you can use `sp_rename`, eg

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.countries.country Type', 'countryType', 'COLUMN';
```

This code has been tested on a Synapse dedicated SQL pool.

That particular API (`sysnapsesql.read`) cannot handle views unfortunately. You would have to materialise it eg using a CTAS in a prior Synapse Pipeline step. The API useful for simple patterns (get table -> process -> put back) but is pretty limited. You can't even manage table distribution (hash, round_robin, replicate) or indexing (clustered columnstore, clustered index, heap) or partitioning but you never know they might add to it one day. I'll be keeping on eye out during the next MS conference anyway.

Comment: Any updates on this?  I've added my comments as an answer.  Please consider upvoting or marking as answer if you have found them useful.

Comment: Yes I have update. Issue is that renaming columns is not the solution. I understand that it solve problem, but in my case I cannot rename columns. Reason is simple, table and columns are used in others processes, and procedures, views, and so on. If I rename the column I will break whole DB. but thanks for help.